# Excel Formula To Get First Non-Zero Value in Row and Return Column Header

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am attempting to find a formula where I can look at a column range within a row and return the column header in that row where the first non-zero value occurs, moving left to right.

Below is a screenshot of my data:
[image]

The results I would want to see in column H would be as follows, for each row:

```
9 = 10/31/2011
10 = 11/30/2011
11 = 11/30/2011
12 = 12/31/2011
```

I have played around with some array formulas and searched through functions, but have not found any sucess yet. I am hoping another excel wizard may have an idea.

I want to avoid writing a UDF for now, if I can.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure, try this

`=INDEX(J$8:N$8,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J9:N9<>0,),0))`

Comment: thanks for that. I found another way to do it, but yours is more elegant and clear :)

Comment: Is the second `INDEX` there to avoid entering as an array formula?

Comment: The first argument to INDEX: `J9:N9<>0`, two questions: 1) Which of the INDEX() forms is being used, the "Array form" or the "Reference form"? 2) What is the Excel word for this concept of comparing a range (?) i.e. J9:N9, to a single value (?) like 0

Comment: @TheRedPea I'm not sure specifically what this is called, but it's an *array formula* in general. The `J8:N8` refers to the titles where the next index is looking for non-zero values, if that helps.

Comment: would be helpful to understand better what the formula does and why it works.

Answer (score 3):

I accepted the answer above but wanted to show the other way I found to do it, in case it helps anyone.

```
=OFFSET($I$8,0,MATCH(0,J10:N10,1)+1)
```

You could also write this as:

```
=INDEX(J$8:N$8,MATCH(0,J9:N9,1)+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Accepted [answer](https://superuser.com/users/116196/raystafarian) by @raystafarian with added explainer:

```
=INDEX(J$8:N$8,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J9:N9<>0,),0))
```

The [INDEX function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd#:%7E:text=The%20INDEX%20function%20returns%20a,within%20a%20table%20or%20range.&text=There%20are%20two%20ways%20to,specified%20cells%2C%20see%20Reference%20form.) returns a value or the reference to a value from within a table or range.

```
INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])
```

The [MATCH function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) searches for a specified item in a range of cells and then returns the relative position of that item in the range.

```
MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
```

So in this case,

```
=INDEX(J9:N9<>0,)
```

Returns a Boolean array. In this case for row 9, 10, 11 and 12:
[image]

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J9:N9<>0,),0)
```

Gives the position (relative column number) of the first match, so 1 for row 9, 2 for row 10 and 11 and 3 for row 12

```
=INDEX(J$8:N$8,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J9:N9<>0,),0))
```

uses the relative column position number (1,2,2 and 3) to get the actual value from array J$8:N$8

Answer (score 0):

Well ! if the requirement is just placing values of J8 : N8 in column H, then Copy and transpose (Paste Option) should solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question asked for a formula.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't get the above to work, as the formula would return the largest column (number) that was non-zero. I used =MATCH(SMALL(J10:N10,1),J10:N10,0). The small ignores zero values.